# When issuing a command to MySQL, I'm getting that error "#1075 - Incorrect table definition;"

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE onscreen( 
   id int(2) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   subject varchar(100) not null,
   content varchar(100) not null,
   date datetime not null
);
```

Comment: probably the keyword `date` as name of a column is the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire error message is:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

This is clear enough: MySQL requires that you define the auto-increment column as a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE onscreen( 
    id int(2) not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,  --> here
    subject varchar(100) not null, 
    content varchar(100) not null, 
    date datetime not null 
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5c2b0c285ee8e56c19719124ca50630)**